# how to take multiple input and print output in php

Tags: php, html

```
    <body>
    <div class="input-div">
    <form action="" method="get">
        <input type="number" name="number[]" placeholder="Enter number" id="num">
        <input type="number"name="number[]" placeholder="Enter table length" id="num2">
        <input type="submit" id="button" value="Submit">
    </form>
    </div>

    <div class="output-div">
    <table>
    <?php
if (isset($_GET['number[]'])):
    $num = count($_GET['number[]']);
    for ($i = 0; $i <= $num; $i++):
        $var = $_GET[0];
        $max = $_GET[1];
    endfor;
    getTable($var, $max);
endif;

function getTable($var, $max)
{
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $max; $i++) {
        if (($i % 2) == 0):
            return isEven($var, $i);
        else:
            return isODD($var, $i);
        endif;
    }
}
function isEven($var, $i)
{
    echo "<tr style= \" background-color: grey;\">";
    echo "<td>" . $var . "</td>";
    echo "<td> * </td>";
    echo "<td>" . $i . "</td>";
    echo "<td> = </td>";
    echo "<td>" . $var * $i . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";

}
function isOdd($var, $i)
{
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $var . "</td>";
    echo "<td> * </td>";
    echo "<td>" . $i . "</td>";
    echo "<td> = </td>";
    echo "<td>" . $var * $i . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}

?>
    </table>
    </div>
</body>
```

please help how to print output.
task is to take 2 numbers.
1st number will be whose table need to output.
and 2nd number is for how long will be the table.
i am trying to print output and not able to find the issue.
what i am doing wrong?
I just started php so do not know much.
All help and hints are welcomed, thank you .

Comment: I'd say you're overcomplicating. No need for array notation here, just give your inputs two different names and work with them directly.

Comment: Take out the [] after number. $var = $_GET['number'][0]; You have : on your if and else. php may be treating them as labels not commands.

Comment: Get rid of your returns. You will never print more than 1 item. return is taking you out of the function. It's not returning anything any way.

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can get rid of two functions `isEven` and `isOdd` and just play with `$style` if even set to `"background-color: grey;"`, Otherwise leave it blank

```html
<form action="" method="get">
        <input type="number" name="number[]" placeholder="Enter number" id="num">
        <input type="number"name="number[]" placeholder="Enter table length" id="num2">
        <input type="submit" id="button" value="Submit">
    </form>
```

```php
if (isset($_GET['number'])):
        $var = $_GET['number'][0];
        $max = $_GET['number'][1];
        getTable($var, $max);
endif;
```

```php
function getTable($var, $max)
{
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $max; $i++) {
        if (($i % 2) === 0)://Even
            $style = "background-color: grey;";
        else:
            $style = "";
        endif;
        echo "
            <tr style='$style'>
                <td>$var</td>
                <td>*</td>
                <td>$i</td>
                <td>=</td>
                <td>".$var*$i."</td>
            </tr>";
    }
}
```